# If statement not returning else properly

Tags: javascript

I have a function

```
function wrap(n,  p) {
    Let number = n;
    Let power = p;

    let val = n*p
    Let half = val/p

    If(half === n) {
       return true
    } else{ return false  } 
}
```

This function returns false where I give it a value of `wrap(2, 2)`

I tried removing the `else statement` and it returned a "true"...  But in the case where it is meant to return a "false" it returns "undefined" what do I do

Comment: it returns `true` for me.

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors and will not run at all, javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: I don't know why but it either returns all false or undefined whenever I add the else part of the statement

Comment: @baao Indicate them please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly need to you, but this might solve your problem

```js
function wrap(number,  power) {
    let value = number*power;
    let half = value/2;

    return half === number; 
}

console.log(wrap(1, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive, you have a lot of syntax errors, you should use:

- `let` instead of `Let`
- `if` instead of `If`